# Error when updating "cabal-install" from cabal cli

Tags: apt, software-installation, haskell, cabal

I was following [this](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) tutorial on how to install `cabal` on linux.

So far, I successfully installed `cabal-install` from `apt`:

```bsh
sudo apt install cabal-install
```

However, at the step where they upgrade `cabal` with `cabal` itself, I encounter this error:

```
$ cabal install cabal-install Cabal

Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Cabal-3.0.0.0...
Failed to install Cabal-3.0.0.0
Build log ( /home/abstrack/.cabal/logs/Cabal-3.0.0.0.log ):
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-3.0.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error ('/usr/bin/ghc' exited with an error:

/tmp/cabal-tmp-25404/Cabal-3.0.0.0/Distribution/Parsec.hs:134:0:
error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if !(MIN_VERSION_base(4,13,0))
^
)
cabal-install-3.0.0.0 depends on Cabal-3.0.0.0 which failed to install.
hackage-security-0.5.3.0 depends on Cabal-3.0.0.0 which failed to install.
```

I couldn't find exactly

```
Cabal-3.0.0.0/Distribution/Parsec.hs:134:0:
```

(line 9 of the log) on google.

I tried to install only `cabal-install` and `Cabal` separately with the `cabal` cli, but I got the exact same error each time.

How do I work around this error and successfully update `cabal`?